# "Real time" update with Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the webpage that displays "questions" and "answers" for users. Questions are created by admin. I am using PHP.

New requirement has come to update questions/answers for users in "real time" (this is not so real time like in strategy game, but I will call this real time).
When admin created new question, user should see it (new question appears).
When admin closes existing question, then it disappears from user point of view.

I am thinking to create it using ajax and javascript timer- to call ajax each minute and to update results. 
I wonder is this is the right way?

And also I wonder about usability/performance... I really do not need to update those questions for user that were not changed... What are your suggestions to determine, which questions were changed by admin (maybe I should add something like "last_update_date" for question in database and put "last_update_date into hidden field for each question" and compare?

Comment: Is `ajax` a must? if not take a look at [Socket.io](http://socket.io), or [Websockets](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/), those are more "real time" technologies

Comment: It is not must, but I do not use socket.io and websockets and this is not sooo real time (it could be updated each minute and not each sek or similar, so I thought that I can use what I 'can use' without learning new techs for this project).

Comment: if you think its easy to loop each minute then do `socket.on('newQuestion', function () {`, `socket.on('updateQuestion', function () {` google for `long pooling`

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to implement your own logic with Socket.io (as suggested in the comments), you should have a look at some of the services available online.

I've been using [Pusher.com](https://pusher.com/) for some time and is quite happy about it.